Python imaplib b'LOGIN failed.'
My Python imaplib library code has recently stopped working for me.
This is the code I use:
import imaplib
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
imap.login("email@hotmail.com","password")

And this is the response I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\drrup\Documents\Coding\Python\Finance\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    imap.login("email@hotmail.com","password")
  File "C:\Users\drrup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\imaplib.py", line 612, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.IMAP4.error: b'LOGIN failed.'

This is the same response I got if the password was incorrect. However, the password I'm trying now is certainly correct. I tried using both my normal password (with 2FA disabled) and an app password (with 2FA enabled), but both gave the same response. I tried specifying both port="993" and port=993, but again both gave the same response.
Does anyone know what could cause this error? And what could be a possible fix for it? The same code used to work perfectly fine.
Normally it should just log me in without an error, like it used to.

I've seen this in a reddit post.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/vobbaz/can_no_longer_log_into_o365_via_imap_using_imaplib/
Check it out, though I don't know if the case is only basic authentication being deprecated in your case unless your code used to work only 4 years ago.

You pretty much need to be using OAuth to log in with Microsoft.
